# How to call state after location change?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am facing a problem. I want to enter state of another controller. I know that in this case I have to change location to load that other controller but how to I tell it to enter that state?

And what is important I do not want to do it globally, because I know that I can to `$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function(e, newUrl, oldUrl){});` and it will work, but this time I want to do it just this time only.

Does any one had a similar problem? or have any idea how can I do it?

@edit
Additional info that may help:

I have more then one state and default state is not the one I want to enter. I cant call $state.go() becouse it will load this state in my current controller and this is not the effect I want to achive. So this is the reason why I need to change location and state

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand this correct...

Normally you define a state like this:

```
$stateProvider
.state('party', {
   url: '/party',
   templateUrl: 'party.html'
});
```

Frome the docs:

**There are three main ways to activate a state:**

1. Call $state.go(). High-level convenience method.
2. Click a link containing the ui-sref directive
3. Navigate to the url associated with the state

This means, that you can call `$state.go("party") from anywhere in your code. The view will be loaded and any assigned controller as well

You could also do `<a ui-sref="party">Go To Party</a>` in any view and as soon as someone clicks the link you achieve the same.

And using `$location` to navigate to `/party` will also activate the state.

Comment: yes, you are correct but my situation is a bit dofferent, i ahve more then one state and default state is not the one i want to enter. i cant call `$state.go()` becouse it will load this state in my current controller and this is not the effect i want to achive. So this is the reason why i need to change location and state